# error because of umlaut in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Currently I'm trying my first steps in Python by trying to rebuild an Instgram bot.

Unfortunately, every time I run my program I get the error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in
>   position 23: invalid continuation byte

The codeline from the error is:

```
like_button = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-label="Gefällt mir"]').click()
```

The error is caused by the German umlaut "ä" but I have to use it because it is the xpath from the like button.

I already googled and there was the solution to put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the first line.

Unfortunately it did not help.

It would be great if you can give me some advice.

Antuan

Comment: Are you accidentally using Python 2 and you forgot to prefix the unicode string with a `u`?

Comment: Hey, no. I am using python 3.8 (64 bit)

Answer (score -1):

The a with umlaut character AFAIK isn't representable in the UTF8 charset.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

I would try using ISO-8859-1 as the encoding. 
https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html

You can encode the contents of the page at the beginning of your code:
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode("ISO-8859-1")

Or alternatively encode elements as you go in a try/catch to try and isolate special characters.

Comment: hey, I don't really understand how to type that in my program. should I just copy and paste it to the first line of my code?

Comment: please note that this are my first steps in programming at all